# Binaries security check macos

Tags: bash, macos, zsh

I have a folder with binaries on macos added to PATH. I get "binary-name cannot be opened developer can't be verified" when trying to execute them.

I know I can manually verify each binary in system settings, but I have dozens of them. Is there any way how to verify all of them at once or exclude folder from developer check.

Comment: `sudo spctl --master-disable` should do the trick on Catalina (I'm not sure about BigSur and Monterey); well, at least Apple shows a clear message now, before it was something like "The archive is corrupted"

Comment: Are the binaries quarantined? You can use `ls -l@` to view their extended attributes, and if you see `com.apple.quarantine` xattrs listed, that's probably what's triggering the signature checks.

Comment: @GordonDavisson yes, they are quarantined

Comment: `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine  *` solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @morris Excellent! We have some other questions with slightly different symptoms, but the same basic cause & solution, so I'll mark this as a duplicate of those.

Comment: `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine  *` saved the day for me. Thanks @morris